# Combine 5 dictionaries together as save as txt file python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge, save

I have the following 5 dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d2 = {'b': 10, 'c': 11}
d3 = {'e': 13, 'f': 15}
d4 = {'g': 101, 'h': 111}
d5 = {'i': 10, 'j': 11}
```

I would like to merge these five dictionaries and save as a txt file. The output should look like the following:

```
{{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 10, 'c': 11}, {'e': 13, 'f': 15}, {'g': 101, 'h': 111}, {'i': 10, 'j': 11}}
```

or

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'b': 10, 'c': 11, 'e': 13, 'f': 15, 'g': 101, 'h': 111, 'i': 10, 'j': 11}
```

What I tried so far?

```
d = {**d1, **d2, **d3, **d4, **d5}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df.to_csv('output.txt')
```

This doesn't merge and save the output properly. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Check `json.dump(d, file)`

Comment: maybe you are writing ('b') instead ('d') that because you are saying it's not save properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pandas for file handling (for this problem at least).

```
d = {**d1, **d2, **d3, **d4, **d5}
```

merges your dictionaries properly.
To save this data as txt file, you only need python file handling:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    # first convert dictionary to string
    file.write(str(d))
```

Content of file.txt:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 11, 'e': 13, 'f': 15, 'g': 101, 'h': 111, 'i': 10, 'j': 11}
```